# Button not render right after upgraded xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Using xamarin forms to develop a cross platform app, initially the app was built using Xamarin.Forms.2.4.0.38779, target framework was 6.0 and Android support library version 23.3.0. The UI code is:

```
// styles
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DodgerBlue"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="RoundBorderButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="30"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="DodgerBlue"></Setter>
</Style>

<StackLayout Margin="15,0" Spacing="20" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundBorderButtonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Copy"></Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundBorderButtonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Addresses"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Then the vs2017 got updated, so does xamarin forms, so I also updated the project to use latest libraries, with Xamarin.Forms.2.4.0.38779 and android target framework version 8.0, support libraries 26.1.0.1. Then suddenly the button is not rendered correctly. Before update:
[image]

after update:

[image]

Is there anything else I need to do to update xamarin forms?

**Update**

I created a minimum [test case](https://github.com/fluter01/TestButton) to show the problem, in vs create a cross-platform project, the only file changed is TestButton/TestButton/MainPage.xaml. The app screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the codes of `RoundBorderButtonStyle`?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT it's in the post, above the button xaml

Comment: sorry, missed that, I'll have a try by my side.

Comment: Just tried with support lib 26 and target framework 8.0, but failed to reproduce the problem. Could you please try it on other device/emulator?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I tried with tablet emulator, still the same issue.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo through online repository that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I've updated my post with a test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I also updated the project to use latest libraries, with Xamarin.Forms.2.4.0.38779 and android target framework version 8.0, support libraries 26.1.0.1. Then suddenly the button is not rendered correctly

I reproduced the problem with your project,and I found it was caused by the `Xamarin.Forms` library. I noticed in your sample project the version of `Xamarin.Forms` is latest(2.4.0.74863).

Solution: By downgrading `Xamarin.Forms` to `2.4.280` and do a clean rebuild and reinstall of the app will fix the problem.

Comment: I downgraded Xamarin Forms to 2.4.0.280 and tried again, but nothing changed. The same problem.

Comment: Have you uninstall the app in your phone/emulator and clean rebuild the app? And also, you need to downgrade the lib both in PCL and Xamarin.Android projects.

Comment: Yes, indeed it works now after uninstalling the app. Thanks.

Comment: So this is be a xamarin forms bug, hope it will be fixed in future releases, downgrading does not sounds like a ultimate solution.